# Are any of the Harvest Moon games multiplayer?

Tags: harvest-moon-series

Harvest Moon seems very similar to Animal Crossing, but can multiple players interact?  Or would multiple players just have multiple independent single player experiences?

Comment: Sort of, Tale of Two Towns has a multiplayer area, but the full game isn't multiplayer: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sj7v5ENbkw

Comment: Cool, the "multiplayer field" seems *kind of* similar to Animal Crossing.  I'll have to read more about it.

Comment: You might also enjoy a LAN indie game, FarmHands : http://www.freelangames.net/2012/09/farm-hands.html . You'd need something like Hamachi to set it up, but it's most enjoyable aspect is figuring out what everything does and finding all the features.

Comment: There's another indie game being developed that might interest you. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=93285018&searchtext=stardew+valley http://www.stardewvalley.net/

Comment: This upcoming game may also be of note: [Stardew Valley](http://stardewvalley.net/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the most part no, Console versions of Harvest Moon have not yet, to my knowledge; I've played 5 of them to date and found no evidence of the latest ones having multiplayer.

The Portable Console Harvest Moons have had some small multiplayer aspects; Harvest Moon GBC 2 and 3 had Trading features but no gameplay, but [Harvest Moon: Tale of Two Towns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sj7v5ENbkw) has simultaneous multiplayer in the Multiplayer field. Sounds like the [3DS version has improved multiplayer aspects](http://www.nintendoworldreport.com/impressions/26673) like Street Pass (and better resolution). Tale of Two Towns is by far the closest to what you're after.

[Rune Factory 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rune_Factory_3:_A_Fantasy_Harvest_Moon), also for the DS, is an RPG style Spin off that has some of the core farming gameplay which also has a multiplayer dungeon. It would be the best/deepest multiplayer experience, but incorporates many RPG elements like combat as well as farming.

Comment: rune factory 3 is quite fun, I like it more than harvest moon and yes, its got some rudimentary multiplayer.  The challenging part of multiplayer for these games is the fact that time freezes while you are inside, but how do you handle that with multiple people?

Comment: @yx. true, I think that's why multi is always confined to certain areas.